# Mapping the map datatype on grails with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, grails, dictionary, grails-orm

I have a domain class called `Regra` which has the following code:

```
Map<String, Permissao> permissoes = [:]
static hasMany = [permissoes: Permissao]
```

This was working fine while I was using the default in-memory grails database (`jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`).

But when I started using SQL Server, some errors started appearing on the console log.

When I try to add an entry to the `Regra` domain class for the first time, I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number. Stacktrace follows:
Message: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    Line | Method
->>   38 | doToString               in org.compass.core.converter.basic.AbstractNumberConverter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    189 | toString                 in org.compass.core.converter.basic.AbstractBasicConverter
|     54 | marshall . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    435 | convertId                in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.ClassMappingConverter
|    410 | marshallIds . . . . . .  in     ''
|     87 | marshallIds              in org.compass.core.marshall.DefaultMarshallingStrategy
|     76 | doMarshall . . . . . . . in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.ReferenceMappingConverter
|     48 | marshall                 in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.AbstractRefAliasMappingConverter
|    213 | doMarshall . . . . . . . in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.ClassMappingConverter
|     97 | marshall                 in     ''
|    154 | marshall . . . . . . . . in org.compass.core.marshall.DefaultMarshallingStrategy
|    408 | create                   in org.compass.core.impl.DefaultCompassSession
|    397 | create . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    305 | create                   in org.compass.core.impl.ExistingCompassSession
|    218 | doInsert . . . . . . . . in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.HibernateEventListener
|    101 | doInCompassWithoutResult in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.HibernateEventListener$1
|     29 | doInCompass . . . . . .  in org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult
|    133 | execute                  in org.compass.core.CompassTemplate
|    151 | executeForMirror . . . . in org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
|     99 | onPostInsert             in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.HibernateEventListener
|     50 | $tt__save . . . . . . .  in security.RegraController
|    200 | doFilter                 in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    449 | executeChain             in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter
|    365 | call . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1
|     90 | doCall                   in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable
|     83 | call . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    383 | execute                  in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject
|    362 | doFilterInternal . . . . in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter
|    125 | doFilter                 in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                      in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

If I make any change to the `Regra` domain class (even things like adding a blank line), and wait until Grails reloads this class, then everything works fine.

And this is the stacktrace I get when I restart the server after the table Regra already has some data:

```
2014-04-04 08:42:09,281 [Compass Gps Index [pool-8-thread-14]] ERROR indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer  - {hibernate}: Failed to index the database
Message: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    Line | Method
->>   38 | doToString               in org.compass.core.converter.basic.AbstractNumberConverter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    189 | toString                 in org.compass.core.converter.basic.AbstractBasicConverter
|     54 | marshall . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    435 | convertId                in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.ClassMappingConverter
|    410 | marshallIds . . . . . .  in     ''
|     87 | marshallIds              in org.compass.core.marshall.DefaultMarshallingStrategy
|     76 | doMarshall . . . . . . . in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.ReferenceMappingConverter
|     48 | marshall                 in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.AbstractRefAliasMappingConverter
|    213 | doMarshall . . . . . . . in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.ClassMappingConverter
|     97 | marshall                 in     ''
|    154 | marshall . . . . . . . . in org.compass.core.marshall.DefaultMarshallingStrategy
|    408 | create                   in org.compass.core.impl.DefaultCompassSession
|    397 | create . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    305 | create                   in org.compass.core.impl.ExistingCompassSession
|    212 | flush . . . . . . . . .  in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer$RowBuffer
|    206 | close                    in     ''
|    151 | performIndex . . . . . . in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer
|    104 | doInCompassWithoutResult in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1$1
|     29 | doInCompass . . . . . .  in org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult
|    133 | execute                  in org.compass.core.CompassTemplate
|    147 | executeForIndex . . . .  in org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
|    102 | call                     in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                      in java.lang.Thread

Error |
2014-04-04 08:42:09,615 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Failed to index, execution exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDeviceException: {hibernate}: Failed to index the database; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
Message: Failed to index, execution exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDeviceException: {hibernate}: Failed to index the database; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    Line | Method
->>  126 | performIndex       in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    119 | index              in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.AbstractParallelGpsDevice
|     42 | buildIndexIfNeeded in org.compass.gps.impl.DefaultReplaceIndexCallback
|    281 | firstStep          in org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager$ReplaceIndexOperationCallback
|    218 | doOperate . . . .  in org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager
|    266 | doReplaceIndex     in     ''
|    261 | replaceIndex . . . in     ''
|    118 | doIndex            in org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
|    154 | index . . . . . .  in org.compass.gps.impl.AbstractCompassGps
|    128 | index              in     ''
|     49 | index . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.CompassGpsUtils
|    157 | doCall             in SearchableGrailsPlugin$_closure3
|    262 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ExecutionException: org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDeviceException: {hibernate}: Failed to index the database; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
->>  122 | report             in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    188 | get                in     ''
|    122 | performIndex . . . in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor
|    119 | index              in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.AbstractParallelGpsDevice
|     42 | buildIndexIfNeeded in org.compass.gps.impl.DefaultReplaceIndexCallback
|    281 | firstStep          in org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager$ReplaceIndexOperationCallback
|    218 | doOperate . . . .  in org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager
|    266 | doReplaceIndex     in     ''
|    261 | replaceIndex . . . in     ''
|    118 | doIndex            in org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
|    154 | index . . . . . .  in org.compass.gps.impl.AbstractCompassGps
|    128 | index              in     ''
|     49 | index . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.CompassGpsUtils
|    157 | doCall             in SearchableGrailsPlugin$_closure3
|    262 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                in java.lang.Thread

Caused by HibernateGpsDeviceException: {hibernate}: Failed to index the database; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
->>  172 | performIndex       in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    104 | doInCompassWithoutResult in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1$1
|     29 | doInCompass . . .  in org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult
|    133 | execute            in org.compass.core.CompassTemplate
|    147 | executeForIndex .  in org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
|    102 | call               in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1
|    262 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
->>   38 | doToString         in org.compass.core.converter.basic.AbstractNumberConverter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    189 | toString           in org.compass.core.converter.basic.AbstractBasicConverter
|     54 | marshall . . . . . in     ''
|    435 | convertId          in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.ClassMappingConverter
|    410 | marshallIds . . .  in     ''
|     87 | marshallIds        in org.compass.core.marshall.DefaultMarshallingStrategy
|     76 | doMarshall . . . . in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.ReferenceMappingConverter
|     48 | marshall           in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.AbstractRefAliasMappingConverter
|    213 | doMarshall . . . . in org.compass.core.converter.mapping.osem.ClassMappingConverter
|     97 | marshall           in     ''
|    154 | marshall . . . . . in org.compass.core.marshall.DefaultMarshallingStrategy
|    408 | create             in org.compass.core.impl.DefaultCompassSession
|    397 | create . . . . . . in     ''
|    305 | create             in org.compass.core.impl.ExistingCompassSession
|    212 | flush . . . . . .  in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer$RowBuffer
|    206 | close              in     ''
|    151 | performIndex . . . in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer
|    104 | doInCompassWithoutResult in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1$1
|     29 | doInCompass . . .  in org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult
|    133 | execute            in org.compass.core.CompassTemplate
|    147 | executeForIndex .  in org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps
|    102 | call               in org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1
|    262 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run                in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Is this exception thrown in an indexing action? As far as I can see it could be a mapping issue between the domain class and the search index.

Comment: Add both domain classes to question. At least reflecting the actual implementation, if actual classes cannot be added.

Comment: @ManuelVio I do have the `searchable` plugin installed. I excluded `permissoes` from searchable's index and it worked.(`static searchable = { except = ['id', 'version','permissoes'] }` Thanks, please submit an answer so I can give the award.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can read from the stacktrace seems that the exception is thrown in an indexing action. It could be a mapping issue between the domain class and the search index.